# pcre2 UTF32 usage

Tags: c++, unicode, pcre, utf

I've just spent some time figuring out the pcre2 interface and think I've got it for the most part. I want to support UTF32, pcre2 is already built with support and code point width has been set to 32.

The code below is what I've got for working with code point width set to 8.
How do I change this to work with UTF32?

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <pcre2.h>

TEST(PCRE2, example) {
//iterate over all matches in a string
  PCRE2_SPTR subject = (PCRE2_SPTR) string("this is it").c_str();
  PCRE2_SPTR pattern = (PCRE2_SPTR) string("([a-z]+)|\\s").c_str();
  int errorcode;
  PCRE2_SIZE erroroffset;
  pcre2_code *re = pcre2_compile(pattern, PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED, PCRE2_ANCHORED | PCRE2_UTF, &errorcode,
                                 &erroroffset, NULL);
  if (re) {
    uint32_t groupcount = 0;
    pcre2_pattern_info(re, PCRE2_INFO_BACKREFMAX, &groupcount);
    pcre2_match_data *match_data = pcre2_match_data_create_from_pattern(re, NULL);
    uint32_t options_exec = PCRE2_NOTEMPTY;
    PCRE2_SIZE subjectlen = strlen((const char *) subject);
    errorcode = pcre2_match(re, subject, subjectlen, 0, options_exec, match_data, NULL);
    while (errorcode >= 0) {
      PCRE2_UCHAR *result;
      PCRE2_SIZE resultlen;
      for (int i = 0; i <= groupcount; i++) {
        pcre2_substring_get_bynumber(match_data, i, &result, &resultlen);
        printf("Matched:%.*s\n", (int) resultlen, (const char *) result);
        pcre2_substring_free(result);
      }
      // Advance through subject
      PCRE2_SIZE *ovector = pcre2_get_ovector_pointer(match_data);
      errorcode = pcre2_match(re, subject, subjectlen, ovector[1], options_exec, match_data, NULL);
    }
    pcre2_match_data_free(match_data);
    pcre2_code_free(re);
  } else {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression at erroroffset
    PCRE2_UCHAR error[256];
    pcre2_get_error_message(errorcode, error, sizeof(error));
    printf("PCRE2 compilation failed at offset %d: %s\n", (int) erroroffset, (char *) error);
  }
```

Presumably `subject` and `pattern` needs to be converted somehow and `result` would be of the same type? I couldn't find anything in pcre2 header to indicate support for that.
And I guess `subjectlen` would no longer be simply `strlen`.

Finally, I put this example together from having gone through some of the docs and the header, is there anything else I should be doing/worth knowing.

Comment: It was possible to explicitly change the unicode mode the input string is seen by the regex engine with previous versions of pcre by putting the directive `(*UTF32)` (or `(*UTF16)` or `(*UTF8)`) at the very begining of your pattern (so inside the pattern itself). There is indeed nothing about these directives in the pcre2 doc (but you should test). However `(*UTF)` seems to be designed to setup the relevant mode for the target string. (and is in the pcre2 doc: http://pcre.org/pcre2.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left pcre2 in the end, after evaluating RE2, PCRE2 and ICU, I chose ICU. Its unicode support (from what I've seen so far) much more complete than the other two. It also provides a very clean API and lots of utilities for manipulation. Importantly, like PCRE2 provides a perl style regex engine which, out of the box works great with unicode.

Comment: Perl-style you say? `(*SKIP)` (backtracking control), `(?(DEFINE))` (subpatterns), `\g<x>` (recursion), `(?(?=)|)` (conditionals) and a lot more aren't supported. If that's OK for you then all is good but you should be aware of the massive feature differences.

Comment: hmmn, the most important for me is (negative) look ahead assertions, which ICU does have. So I can do `(?!1234)\d{4}`, find me 3 digits that aren't 1234.

Answer (score 1):

If you set code width properly this could be the problem:
`(PCRE2_SPTR) string("this is it").c_str();`

Converting the c_str() to PCRE2_SPTR doesn't make the string utf32.

If you are unsure about setting the proper code width (I didn't see it in your sorce code) you can force 32 bit by adding _32 postfix to everything e.g.  `pcre2_compile_32`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which character type you are going to use and which system you are going to target.

The basic unit for `std::string` is `char` which is generally 8 bit and supports UTF-8 (can be different depending on implementation/system). So you can't use `std::string("some string")` and such codes when dealing with UTF-32 in such systems.

`PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH` must match the bit-size of the basic character unit you are going to use. For 8-bit `char` it should be defined as 8, for 16-bit `char` it should be defined as 16 etc...

In GNU/Linux, you can use `wchar_t` i.e `std::wstring` which is 32 bit and UTF-32 supported. In windows `wchar_t` is 16 bit (with UTF-16).

In `>=C++11`, you can use `char32_t` i.e `std::u32string` which is at least 32 bit (you will have to make sure it's exactly 32 bit in your target system)

I have a [wrapper](https://github.com/jpcre2/jpcre2) for PCRE2 in C++ which contains some examples (in src directory) on how to handle UTF-16 and UTF-32 modes.